How to get text from link preview in telegram message
I want to create a telegram bot that returns the preview text of the link that the user sent to it.
Steps:

User send URL to bot. Telegram displays preview content.
Bot returns the text of this preview.


I use python and telebot.
I checked if this information is in the message properties.
Message properties do not contain this information:
enter image description here

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have a few suggestions on how to improve your post. First, if you believe the content of the Message properties structure is important to your question, please enter them as text formatted as code instead of an image (for the sake of indexing). Second, share some of the code (it would help to understand what tools you are using, and how exactly you are using them).

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
